# How to Run Hotkey on ALL Tabs in a Window in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

Is there a way in Notepad++ to run a hotkey on all the open tabs in that window?

I want to run an XML Tools plugin hotkey command but I have to run it on each tab so it would be productive if the command executed on all the tabs. This would also be helpful for other hotkeys.

For example, the hotkeys in Notepad++ would run on both xml1.xml and xl2.xml tabs shown below.
[image]